# iOS Password Strength Checker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, security, passwords

Looking for suggestions on a password strength checker for objective-c.  I did some googling and didn't find any hits, neither here on SO.  I could write one up but thought I'd check here first - has anyone implemented one?

Comment: I prefer avoiding storing user passwords wherever possible.

Comment: Agreed - though in this case it's unavoidable.  I plan on hashing and following other good practices.  I would like to provide a convenience to my users by having a password meter that actively checks their password as it's entered.

Comment: Do you have a password hash in mind?

Comment: No, what do you recommend?

Comment: My simple password strength checker in C might be helpful if you are trying to build one: https://github.com/hb20007/miscellaneous-programs/tree/master/c-programs/PasswordChecker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am only aware of two half-decent password strength *estimators*: [zxcvbn](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) (in CoffeeScript, compiles to JavaScript) and [Passfault](http://www.passfault.com/) (in Java, appears to be intended as a webapp).

(Actually, that's is a slight lie; there was one in a PhD thesis I read a while back, but I'm not sure where I put the link.)

Every other password "strength" checker I've looked at in any detail has been flawed, often *deeply* flawed (e.g. GRC's "haystacks" assumes a very dumb bruteforce; even open-source password crackers are much more sophisticated) — the other day, the password strength meter of a large UK loyalty card scheme told me that "1Aa" was a "GOOD" password ("GOOD" is the highest rating).

(The other problem is that the password strength required depends on how it's being used: a 48-bit password like "W1mCj6B1" is fine for a Google account but *incredibly* weak as a Windows/Mac login password or a WPA passphrase.)

I don't think you're likely to find a decent one in Objective-C, given their rarity. If you do end up writing one, I have a few suggestions:

- Write it in C (or maybe C++). This won't cost you much and will be far more portable; Objective-C pretty much ties you to OS X and iOS in the same way that .NET ties you to Windows (i.e. in theory you can port the runtime to other platforms; in practice it will be much less used outside of those platforms). To increase usage, you could add an Objective-C API.
- Decide what to do about non-ASCII characters (and non-English languages in general). There are essentially two options:

  - Disallow them (people are used to it, right?)
  - Map to ASCII *for strength estimation*, e.g. by stripping accents (see `NSWidthInsensitiveSearch` and `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`) and jumping through some hoops to map ı/İ/ß to i/I/ss. There's also `kCFStringTransformToLatin` which promises to transliterate most scripts to the Latin alphabet. This bit doesn't need to be in C because it'll heavily depend on Unicode libraries, although you may be able to use ICU.

Finally, password strength estimation is a hard problem. Guess the strength of 
`2jmj7l5rSw0yVb_vlWAYkK_YBwk`. Now ask Google.

Comment: Phenomenal information - great links.  Thanks!  I now realize how in-depth and subjective password estimators are.  I'll do some more reading on the topic and see if I can find a happy medium for my project - luckily I'm not dealing with highly-sensitive user information!

Comment: Passwords *are* "highly-sensitive user information" - password reuse is rampant! IMO that's the biggest reason for avoiding passwords whenever possible: A leaked password DB is easily used to attack users' email accounts, and there's a limit to how much password hashes will protect you (because they have to be fast enough to perform on a busy server).

Answer (score 2):

I have created a method for this purpose. I know this is old question, but I think it actual for now to, so here is the url of code:

> https://github.com/ruben-samsonyan/PasswordStrengthChecker/blob/master/passwordChecker.m

Answer (score 1):

Mattt Thompson created a library for this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218842/924025)). It's the best option I've found.

https://github.com/mattt/Navajo